# Linux utility to interleave contents of two files, line by line

Tags: linux, bash

I wrote a script for interweaving contents of two files. The script goes like this

```
#!/bin/bash

touch t_10.txt

numer1=$(cat $1 | wc -l)
numer2=$(cat $2 | wc -l)

count=1
while [ $count -le $numer1 -a $count -le $numer2 ]
    do
        head -n $count $1 | tail -n 1 >> merge.txt
        head -n $count $2 | tail -n 1 >> merge.txt
        count=$((count + 1))
done

count=$((count-1))
if [ $count -lt $numer1 ]; then
    rem=$(( $numer1 - $count ))
    tail -n $rem $1 >> merge.txt
else
    rem=$(( $numer2 - $count ))
    tail -n $rem $2 >> merge.txt
fi
```

Can you tell me if there is any better cli utility??

Comment: `paste -d '\n'`? Am on mobile so I can't try it out to confirm.

Comment: Not quite, `paste` will print empty lines inbetween, when one file is shorter than the other

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment).

Comment: Please do what the `bash` tag tells you do do before posting a question - copy/paste your script into http://shellcheck.net, fix the issues the tool tells you about, then [edit] your question to show that corrected script instead of the one you currently have if you still have a question so we don't have to consider the impact of those bugs while trying to help you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please read [why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice). The guys who invented `shell` to create/destroy files and processes and sequence calls to tools also invented `awk` for `shell` to call to manipulate text.

```
 $ head file{1,2}
==> file1 <==
foo 1
foo 2
foo 3
foo 4
foo 5

==> file2 <==
BAR 1
BAR 2
BAR 3
```

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
    file2 = ARGV[2]
    ARGV[2] = ""
    ARGC--
}
{ print }
(getline < file2) > 0
END {
    while ( (getline < file2) > 0 ) {
        print
    }
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
foo 1
BAR 1
foo 2
BAR 2
foo 3
BAR 3
foo 4
foo 5
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file2 file1
BAR 1
foo 1
BAR 2
foo 2
BAR 3
foo 3
foo 4
foo 5
```

This is one of the rare occasions where it's appropriate to use `getline`, see http://awk.freeshell.org/AllAboutGetline.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
paste file1 file2 |tr "\t" "\n" >> merge.txt
```

Comment: That would convert any tabs in either of the input files into newlines. If you were going to use `paste` it'd just be `paste -d '\n'` but that would insert blank lines if both files weren't the same length which is not what the OPs script does.